# What is the proper way to use jQuery to trigger an event on click or focus?

Tags: jquery, function, click, focus

For accessibility reasons I need to toggleClass when someone focuses an element with a keyboard OR uses a mouse to click it. Currently it requires 2 clicks to toggleClass the first time. It seems that when I click, focus is negating the click and thus toggleClass fires twice. What is the proper way to accomplish this? Any info is appreciated!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
( function($) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    // Main nav show/hide
    $("#mobile-nav-link").on("focus click", function(e) {
        $( '.mobile-nav, #main-container' ).toggleClass('position-2');
    });
}); 
} ) ( jQuery );
</script>
```

Comment: Just the focus is not sufficient? Whether you focus by mouse or by keyboard it is still just a focus.

Comment: @NawedKhan The element we're clicking is a hamburger/menu icon. If I set the event to focus only, the user is unable to close the menu by clicking on the hamburger/menu icon. A user needs to be able to focus the icon to open the menu and be able to close the menu by clicking if they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think users would expect a hamburger menu to open on focus. The more common behavior would be to allow the hamburger menu to open / close on enter while focused.

Comment: After all this I agree with you. I ended up changing this back to 'click' only and am expecting the user to click/enter to expand the menu. I was trying to do too much. Thanks @mike-thone
`$("#mobile-nav-link").on("click", function(e) {
     $( '.mobile-nav, #main-container' ).toggleClass('position-2');
});`